# How can I get the source code for Komodo Edit?

Tags: open-source, komodoedit

How do I get the source code for Komodo Edit?

[Komodo Edit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveState_Komodo) is an open source text editor. I want to
inspect and learn from the source code for Komodo Edit.

In the download location,
http://downloads.activestate.com/Komodo/releases/5.1.4/, I
can only see binaries. How do I get the full source code?

Comment: It seems that the URLs have been changed  [for browsing online](http://svn.openkomodo.com/openkomodo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the only way is to [get the source code through Subversion](http://wiki.openkomodo.com/index.php/Building_Open_Komodo). From the [Open Komodo Development README](http://svn.openkomodo.com/openkomodo/view/openkomodo/trunk/README.txt):

> The Open Komodo sources are kept in a Subversion repository
>   hosted at the openkomodo.com site. Read-only public access
>   is available via:
>
> svn co http://svn.openkomodo.com/repos/openkomodo/trunk openkomodo

For Windows, using TortoiseSVN (see
[Practical guide to subversion on Windows with TortoiseSVN](http://www.shokhirev.com/nikolai/programs/SVN/svn.html)
for installation, setup and use):

Right click on <folder to receive the source code>/SVN
Checkout/set "URL of repository" to
"http://svn.openkomodo.com/repos/openkomodo/trunk"

The result was 15164 files in 6120 folders, 138 MB transferred, 348 MB on disk.

Including 93 C files, 138 C++ files and 971 Python files.

The source code files can also [be browsed online](http://svn.openkomodo.com/openkomodo/browse/openkomodo/trunk).

Answer (score 8):

The source for Komodo Edit is available on the **[Open Komodo Project's Website](http://www.openkomodo.com/)**.

Answer (score -3):

Start your search with [Komodo Community](http://community.activestate.com/products/Komodo).